# What is the exact effect of declaring a resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I create a style using XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="tbxWithValidation" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource errorTemplate}"/>
        ...
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

what does mean this declaration? Do I create a class or an instance?

I assume I create an instance of class `Style`, but I wonder in this case if this instance will be used each time I use the resource.

In other words, does `Style="{StaticResource tbxWithValidation}"` reuse the same instance, or does it create a new instance so that each control has its own style instance?

I'm asking this question, because while this may be not important for a style (maybe controls can share the same style instance without problems, not sure...), it seems to me there would be a problem with declaring a control template and using it multiple times (this template is used in the style above):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="errorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" Text="!"/>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Can you help me clarifying this (I'm learning WPF)?

Comment: The style isn't reproduced for each usage, it's setting sort-of default values for dependency properties. A template works like any other template you'd use for dress making or a jelly mould. The template says generate instances of these controls each time.  They are not the same controls. If you defined a visual as a resource then that is one unique thing and bad things will happen if you try and use it twice in the same view.

Comment: @Andy, ["bad things will happen if you try and use it twice in the same view"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjz0OwQmfWo&t=1m58s) - ominous. and also wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090738/wpf-style-cant-work-on-multiple-controls

Comment: @Ash If you define a visual as a resource. A visual can only have one parent so the best that will happen is your only get to see the visual once. I'd call that bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="TbxWithValidation" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>
        ...
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

This declaration instructs the XAML parser create an *instance* of the class `Style`.

In this case, the `Style` (or the resource in general) and all nested `ResourceDictionary` or referenced objects (and therefore also the the *ErrorTemplate*) is 'reused' for every reference to it.

This is because of the [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) attribute. This attribute is implicitly set and `true` by default. When `true` this attribute instructs the XAML parser to reuse the instance of the object. You can set it explicitly to `false`:

```
<Style x:Shared="False" x:Key="TbxWithValidation" TargetType="TextBox">
  ...
</Style>
```

By design each instance of an object is allowed to exist only once in the object graph. 'Reuse' or sharing  (`x:Shared="True"`) instructs the XAML parser to internally create a copy of the shared instances, so that the XAML parser can insert them in various places in the element tree. But since this are *copies* they are actually referencing the same shared instance.

An exception is made to all objects that extend `UIElement`. Instances of those objects can only exist once in the object graph: that's why elements like `System.Windows.Controls.Image` will magically disappear when used in multiple positions in the graph e.g. like when a single icon is used with multiple `Button` elements. In this case only one icon at time would be visible.

Instances of `UIElement` can not be shared (referenced by more than one resource instance) - they are unique. This means the author has to create the required number of instances explicitly.
This is why e.g. when creating a `Button` instance in C# (code-behind) and then add it to e.g. two different `Grid` elements the following exception is thrown:

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element.

So, this means a shared resource like a `Style` is only critical when it declares `UIElement` objects (like `Image`) that are referenced in more than one resource:

```
<Style x:Key="SaveButton" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Save"/>                
                <Image Source="Resources\icons\save.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here the XAML parser will reuse the same instance of `Style` (`x:Shared` is `true` by default). To do so it creates copies. But the `Image` can't be copied: it will only appear on one `Button`.
To solve this you would have to mark the `Style` as not shared:

```
<Style x:Shared="False" x:Key="SaveButton" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Save"/>
                <Image Source="Resources\icons\save.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now the XAML parser must create a new instance of the `Style` for each reference.

Something somehow similar applies to `ControlTemplate`. It is also shared by default but not its content.
For each reference to the `ControlTemplate`, new instances of the content elements are created.
Therefore declaring the content of the `Button` as `ControlTemplate` or `ContentTemplate` (instead of setting the `Button.Content` directly via a `Style` like above), would also solve the problem described above.

[`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#static-resources) does not mean that the resource is static. It's a markup extension that instructs the XAML parser to lookup the resource tree to find a predefined instance. Same does [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#dynamic-resources). The only difference is that `StaticResource` instructs the XAML parser to resolve the reference to a resource at compile time, whereas `DynamicResource` let's the XAML parser create an expression instead, that will be evaluated at run time (deferred). `DynamicResource` therefore resolves the resource at run time.

Comment: An answer as we would like to see more often, thanks. Actually this topic is less simple than I assumed initially.